# Error while installing php55w on CentOS

Tags: php, centos6

I am trying to install php55w package on a CentOS vm. I had php54 installed before and removed all the old php packages before updating the new package. When I do sudo yum install php55w I get the following error:

```
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php55w.x86_64 0:5.5.11-1.w5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php55w-common = 5.5.11-1.w5 for package: php55w-5.5.11-1.w5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php55w-cli = 5.5.11-1.w5 for package: php55w-5.5.11-1.w5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: php55w-5.5.11-1.w5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd for package: php55w-5.5.11-1.w5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.6()(64bit) for package: php55w-5.5.11-1.w5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) for package: php55w-5.5.11-1.w5.x86_64
---> Package php55w-opcache.x86_64 0:5.5.11-1.w5 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.15-15.el6.centos.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-tools = 2.2.15-15.el6.centos.1 for package: httpd-2.2.15-15.el6.centos.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: apr-util-ldap for package: httpd-2.2.15-15.el6.centos.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /etc/mime.types for package: httpd-2.2.15-15.el6.centos.1.x86_64
---> Package openssl098e.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-17.el6.centos.2 will be installed
---> Package php55w-cli.x86_64 0:5.5.11-1.w5 will be installed
---> Package php55w-common.x86_64 0:5.5.11-1.w5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: php55w-common-5.5.11-1.w5.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package apr-util-ldap.x86_64 0:1.3.9-3.el6_0.1 will be installed
---> Package httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.2.15-15.el6.centos.1 will be installed
---> Package mailcap.noarch 0:2.1.31-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package php55w-common.x86_64 0:5.5.11-1.w5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: php55w-common-5.5.11-1.w5.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php55w-common-5.5.11-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic-el5)
           Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I am stuck with this for a long time now. Don't know how to work around this. I am relatively new to CentOS too. Let me know if you have any questions!

Thanks,

Comment: maybe this help you: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5028

Comment: I enabled rpmforge even that doesn't help. Saw that article before posting here :(

Answer (score 4):

You've installed webtatic-el5 on an el6 server, try the el6 version

```
yum remove webtatic5-release
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
```

Comment: it helped me in 6.6 version

Answer (score 1):

```
Error: Package: php55w-common-5.5.11-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic-el5)
           Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
```

Likely php55w-common build with more new version of libcurl.so.3.

You need update libcurl package before install php55w-common.

Also check

```
# yum provides '*/libcurl.so.*';
```

May be libcurl.so.3 is not packaged.

Comment: Its already updated to libcurl-7.28.1-2.el6.x86_64 and libcurl-devel-7.28.1-2.el6.x86_64

Comment: Yes its not packaged. Its got only libcurl.so.4

How do I get libcurl.so.3? Been Googling for the same for a while actually..

Comment: What is link are you use to install rpmforge repo?

Comment: # wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release- 0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm

# rpm -Uvh rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm

# wget http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
# rpm --import RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
 
# yum --enablerepo=rpmforge install php55w-common

Comment: No package php55w-common available. php55w does not exist to rpmforge repo.